# PHP shortening, echo variable if defined

Tags: php

Is there any way to shorten this code ?

```
<?= isset($email)?$email:''; ?>
```

I feel it's kind of stupid to repeat $email. I've tried

```
<?= isset($email)?:''; ?>
```

But it echoes the boolean coming from isset instead.

Comment: It's probably terrible practice, but you could use `@$email` to say "this might not be set but I don't care."

Comment: I don't think there is but would be interested in hearing different.

Comment: Yes, it can be the solution <?=@$mail;?>

Comment: Why would this be "bad practise"?

Comment: I don't know why, but I hate them <?= tags, I find them so evil. (yes I know thing to do with post)

Comment: Relevant to the question http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php

Comment: @Gavin normally considered bad practice to suppress notices/warnings which is what the @ does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom function:

```
function safeEcho(&$var) {
    if (isset($var))
        return $var;

    return null;
}
```

and call this function:

```
<?= safeEcho($var) ?>
```

Comment: This is wrong in two ways : 1) A function that returns a value should NOT be called `safeEcho`. 2) This isn't as "safe" as you think - it will issue `E_NOTICE` if a `$email` isn't set

Comment: Edited (variable pass by reference) as per @Dave Just

Comment: @DaveJust you're right, at first, I had a wrong concept in mind when writing the function. Surely, there are better names possible.

Comment: @TheWolf Which version of PHP are you on? All variables are passed by reference since version 5.3.0 and use of & is deprecated. Removed from 5.4.0 onwards. http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Answer (score 2):

```
<?= isset($email)?$email:''; ?> // is the shortest way to do it.
```

Comment: If short tags is off then you must use <?php echo isset($email)?$email:'' ?> this is the version of the code that will always work.

Answer (score 1):

The only way of "shorting" that, is a custom function.

```
function get(&$email) { // <- Note, there must be a reference!!!
  return isset($email) ? $email : '';
} 

<?= get($email); ?>
```

If you pass `$email` without a reference, then `isset()` will issue a `E_NOTICE` if a variable isn't set. This is because you pass to `isset()` a copy of undefined variable, not a variable itself.

Comment: it depends on what php version you are talking, starting from some version everything is passed by reference.

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly citation needed

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php `Note: There is no reference sign on a function call - only on function definitions. Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass the argument by reference. As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use & in foo(&$a);. And as of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was removed, so using it will raise a fatal error.`

Comment: This is exactly what is happening here: Reference sign on function definition, no reference sign on function call.

Comment: You don't need the reference sign at all unless you are using PHP < 5.3.0 in which case you need to upgrade.